# What is the Islamic view of 'Chimera'? Who will their children belong to as per Sharia?

Tags: fiqh, science, inheritance

A chimera is essentially a single organism that's made up of cells from two or more "individuals"—that is, it contains two sets of DNA, with the code to make two separate organisms. *One way that chimeras can happen naturally in humans is that a fetus can absorb its twin.*

I stumbled across a 2015 case where a child's DNA turned to be his uncles and not his father. But what was more shocking was that the father didn't have a brother!

What science learned from this changed our entire perspective. The father was a chimera who absorbed his fraternal twin, who also happened to be a male. Inside, the father’s sperm was 90% himself and 10% his twin brother.

His son only inherited the absorbed brother’s sperm, though. From this, a man who was never born managed to have a child of his own.

From an Islamic perspective, I'd like to inquire who can we consider the father to be?

**Link:** https://time.com/4091210/chimera-twins/

**P.S**
I understand that such genetic details might not have been available 1400+ years ago. But do the ulema of today have any ijtehad on such matters from Hadiths?